# Default user profile for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I want windows 10 to treat my current profile as default profile for all other users added in future. How to do that.

Comment: What research have you done? There is a lot of good documentation on setting up profiles, and you'll need to show some "homework" here so we know what you've tried and what we don't need to suggest.

Comment: Tried to copy all the details to default folder in users folder. And tried to use sysprep. But sysprep is telling to store for another pC. And I want on same PC. Also my aysprep is not running

Comment: After copying all data from my current profile to new profile when I am trying to sign in new user, it shows "User profile service failed the sign in. User profile can not be loaded".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand if you're trying to do that for testing purposes, to create a backup profile of your own in case of trouble, or if you really want new users (meaning, not you) to use the exact same set of parameters as you when their accounts will be created, but the simplest way to achieve what you (seem to) want is to point at your own profile when creating a new user account. The new username will de facto create a new user profile folder in your existing profile folder, making the new user a child of your parent profile. Same rights and permissions, too, though.

Comment: I want the newly created users to use the exact same set of parameters as I am having now.

Comment: So how to.point to my own user profile during creating a new user account. And by this will I be getting all my settings like apps, programmes, settings for programmes etc. In my new user created.

Comment: No, you don't actually want an exact copy. There are settings and things that are unique to your profile, and you've probably broken your system by doing what you've done. You need to list EXACTLY what you want in the new users profiles, and copy ONLY THOSE THINGS that need to be there.

Comment: Yes. I broke up my PC but I do have a system image to restore. I want all the apps and programes and their settings to each new user created.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Profile Setup Account
1.  Create a new local user account named ProfileSetup (Note: the name does not matter but should be something that would not match another string in the stock Windows registry. You will be searching the registry for the name of the user you use to configure the profile. Using a unique name will make this easier.)
a.  Open Control Panel > Add or remove user accounts
b.  If there is already an account named ProfileSetup and you want to start over with a new account, delete the existing account and then create a new one:
i.  Click on the ProfileSetup user
ii. Click Delete the account
iii.    Click Delete Files
iv. Click Delete Account
c.  Click Create a new account
d.  Enter the account name: ProfileSetup
e.  Click the radio button next to Administrator
f.  Click Create Account
2.  Set the password for the ProfileSetup account
a.  Click on the ProfileSetup account
b.  Click Create a password
c.  Enter the password and click Create password
Configure the User Profile for the Profile Setup Account
1.  Logout as Administrator and login as ProfileSetup
If you intend to arrange the icons on the desktop, use a screen size of 1024x768 when logged in as ProfileSetup.  This is the default screen size that most users will use when they connect to VCL reservations.  If you arrange the icons using a custom screen size, the icons most users see will be rearranged when they connect using the default size.
2.  Customize the user profile while logged in as ProfileSetup account (configure the desktop background, arrange icons, etc).  The following tips are optional:
Copy the Customized Profile to Default
1.  Logout as ProfileSetup and login as Administrator
2.  Rename the ProfileSetup user profile folder to Default:
a.  Open a Windows Explorer window and navigate to C:\Users
b.  Rename the original default profile folder: C:\Users\Default -> C:\Users\DefaultOriginal
c.  Rename the customized profile folder: C:\Users\ProfileSetup -> C:\Users\Default
Note: if you are unable to rename the ProfileSetup folder, reboot the computer, login as Administrator, and try again. Run the following command from a command prompt to reboot the computer:
shutdown.exe -r -f -t 0
3.  Copy the customized profile folder using the Windows profile copying utility:
Note: Windows 7 only allows its built-in profile copying utility to be used to copy the default profile, not profiles of other user accounts. The profile you customized now resides in the default profile location (C:\Users\Default) so the utility can now be used to make a copy of it.
a.  Open Control Panel > System and Security > System
b.  Click Advanced system settings on the left
c.  Click the Settings... button under User Profiles
d.  Highlight Default Profile
e.  Click Copy To…
i.  Copy profile to: C:\Users\DefaultCopy
ii. Click Change under Permitted to use
iii.    Enter Everyone and click OK
iv. Click OK
4.  Replace the original customized profile directory with the one created by the Windows profile copying utility
Note: C:\Users\Default contains the original customized profile. The same profile also resides in C:\Users\DefaultCopy. The DefaultCopy folder is the one which has had the Windows profile copying utility transformations applied to it.
a.  Open Windows Explorer
b.  Delete the “C:\Users\Default folder
c.  Rename the folder: C:\UsersDefaultCopy -> C:\Users\Default
5.  Delete the ProfileSetup account:
a.  Open Control Panel > Add or remove user accounts
b.  Click on the ProfileSetup account
c.  Click Delete the account
d.  Click Delete Files
e.  Click Delete Account
Clean the Registry for the Customized Profile
1.  While logged in as Administrator
2.  Run regedit.exe
3.  Select the HKEY_USERS hive:

4. Click the File menu and select Load Hive:
5. Browse to C:\Users\Default
6. Enter ntuser.dat in the File name: field (Note: this file is hidden so it normally is not displayed in the list of files)
7. Enter a Key Name: DU
8. Navigate to: HKEY_USERS\DU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders

You will probably see the path to the ProfileSetup account's original user profile directory saved in many of the values as highlighted below.  This can cause problems with programs which use these values.  For example, a user may save a file to the Desktop from within a program, but the saved file doesn't appear on the user's desktop.

9. Delete all of the values under Shell Folders except for (Default) and "!Do not use this registry key":
10. Select the DU key in the left pane
11. Click on the Edit menu and select Find...
12. Search the DU key for the string ProfileSetup.  In general, you want to clean up everything that references the user named ProfileSetup and the C:\Users\ProfileSetup directory.  There will probably be several places under DU where these are saved.  You will need to analyze each match.  Most matches won't cause problems.  Some will such as the Shell Folders key you previously cleaned up.
13. IMPORTANT: Unload the Default user registry hive:
    a.  Select the DU key
    b.  Click the File menu and select Unload hive...
    Any new local user accounts created on the computer should receive a user profile configured with the customizations you made to the Profile account.

Copied from 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/VCL/How+to+Configure+the+Windows+Default+User+Profile